# Accessing extern variable in static lib from exe and dll

Tags: c++

In my project, I have an exe, a dll and a static lib.

The dependencies are as follows:

```
 exe -> dll -> lib
  |             ^
  |_____________|
```

The exe depends on both the dll and lib while the dll depends on the lib.

In `libfile.h`

```
struct A {
   A(int i) : x(i) {}
   int x;
};
extern A* ptr;
```

and in `libfile.cpp`, I have `A* ptr = nullptr;`

In `exefile.cpp`

```
#include "libfile.h"
__declspec(dllimport) void foo();
int main() {
  ptr = new A(10);
  foo();
  delete ptr;
}
```

In `dllfile.cpp`

```
 #include "libfile.h"
__declspec(dllexport) void foo();
__declspec(dllexport) void foo() { 
    int a = ptr->x; //error, ptr is nullptr 
}
```

How can I get access to the `A* ptr` in lib from both the exe and dll without passing it as a function parameter? I've tried using an interface function in dll to return `ptr` to exe but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dll and exe have different memory locations for that `ptr`. I'm assuming here that you have `ptr` declared in the exe otherwise you will get a linking error (i'm looking at this line `ptr = new A(10);`). Changing one will not effect the other.

To "nice" way get around this is to export from the dll a getter and a setter function for ptr (just like you did with foo):

```
__declspec(dllexport) A* getPtr() { return ptr; }
__declspec(dllexport) void setPtr(A* new_value) { ptr = new_value; }
```

In the exe just declare `getPtr/setPtr` as `dllimport` and use those to interact with the `ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

If an exe, DLL, or multiple DLL's (or Linux so) consume the same static library, then they each get a *copy* of that library. This means all global and static variables are separate, could even be different versions of the static library (e.g. if you changed the static library, recompiled the exe and did not recompile the DLL).

If you want the resources in that library to be shared, you will need to do that by other means. For example you could:

- Make the static library into another DLL
- Statically link everything
- Avoid the globals in the shared static library and pass everything as function parameters